# Filtration in the List based on "User!UserID"

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008, mdx

Goal:
To make a filtration in the table list with support of "where" statement based on SSRS:s built-in function "User!UserID" in SSRS.

Problem:
I need apply the output value of the code

```
REPLACE
(

    MID
    (
        User!UserID,
        InStr(User!UserID,"\")+1, 
        Len(User!UserID)
    ),
    ".",
    " "
)
```

in the dataset, inside of Where statement, but I retrieve error.

I also tried to apply the sourcecode as a variable and use it in the dataset, but the query designer complain that the variable do not exist. I'm using MDX code

What should I do?

```
WHERE
(
    FILTER
    (
        xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.ALLMEMBERS AS c, 
        c.Current.Name =
        REPLACE
        (

            MID
            (
                User!UserID,
                InStr(User!UserID,"\")+1, 
                Len(User!UserID)
            ),
            ".",
            " "
        )

    )
)
```

Comment: You have to add the parameter in the query designer for your dataset when you have an MDX query. This will take care of the error message saying it doesn't exist. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156303.aspx

Comment: How to enable to add the sourcode and its value to a parameter? I have read the link and the value is not being taken from a dimension table or similiar. The foundation of the value is from User!UserId and how to connect it to a parameter?

Comment: You have a report parameter and a query parameter.  For the query parameter, you define it as described in the link above.  You must also have the report parameter with the same name. You can set the value you have in your code as the default value in the report parameter.

Comment: I have read again the content and its title "To define a query parameter in MDX in Query mode" but unfortunately, it doesn't inform me about how to apply the code och its data of "User!UserID" to apply it to a query parameter. The instruction is fitable when you already have av dimension table to apply it for a query parameter. The code "User!UserID" do not contain in the dimension table for query designer.

Comment: You define the value in the report parameter, not the query parameter. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220464.aspx#bkmk_Report_Parameters

Comment: If I understand right, wHen I have added the code in the report parameter, I go to the dataset and apply the name of the parameter in the mdx code without using "to define a query parameter in MDX in Query mode". Is it correct?

Comment: You need to define both a report parameter and a query parameter. They will be linked together by referencing the report parameter in the definition of the query parameter, which is why you will want them to be named the same. The value you define in the report parameter will be fed to the query parameter.

Comment: I understand. I have more follow-up issue. 1. wHen I have added the code in the report parameter,    2. I enter to the dataset and go to the place to "to define a query parameter in MDX in Query mode"   3. Typing and defining the name of the parameter in the Parameter column, click <Enter Parameter>, and then type the name of a parameter.  ---- The main question is. What should I apply in the Dimension, Hierarchy column?

Comment: I assumed you are passing the user id to the where clause because you have a dimension that contains user IDs.  If not, can you update your question to discuss how you would use the User ID in your query in the first place.  Also, I'm not sure you mean to use the filter statement in your where clause.

Comment: "I assumed you are passing the user id to the where clause because you have a dimension that contains user IDs.". A. Yes it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

1.
You apply the code

```
        REPLACE
    (

        MID
        (
            User!UserID,
            InStr(User!UserID,"\")+1, 
            Len(User!UserID)
        ),
        ".",
        " "
    )
```

in a new parameter, default value.

1. select dataset and go to the query designer and add a new parameter. The new parameter shall have same common with other data with similiar first and last name in from the dimension table.

3.add the parameter code in the query designer mode with mdx coding.